# Cron job that renames media files based on time

Tags: php, indexing, cron, html5-video, file-rename

I have a media file that I would like to present to users on my site based on time of day.  I would like to use a CRON job to rename the files so that I can easily manage the media being displayed.

i.e.

default media displayed on site is default.mp4

default.mp4 renamed to 0.mp4 at 03:00 and 1.mp4 is renamed to default.mp4

default.mp4 renamed to 1.mp4 at 03:00 and 2.mp4 renamed to default.mp4

default.mp4 renamed to 2.mp4 at 03:00 and 3.mp4 renamed to default.mp4

and so on....

what is the CRON job syntax for this?

Comment: Just remember you lose all statistics about videos played, if you use this approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a script at 03:00 every day:

```
0 3 * * * *
```

Though I'm guessing you copy-pasted those lines & neglected to update the time, as what you're asking will cause multiple files to be renamed `default.mp4` at the same time.

Here's a good site for explaining CRON syntax: http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

This is a good one for testing: https://crontab.guru/